# Css sticky footer without overlapping content

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked quite a lot but all answers suffer the same problem of overlapping content. I would like to have a page (I'm working with Angular btw) composed of two items.

item 1: content which is filled in depending on the component (i.e. the route). This component can choose its size itself, so it may choose to pick all remaining space, or it may choose to take only the space it needs.

item 2: a sticky footer. I.e. a footer which is always visible, no matter how large the content is.

Now, all answers I could find define either a fixed height for the content and then apply a footer with style `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0`. (or sometimes `position: absolute`) Yet I do not want to impose a fixed height on the content. Other solutions have a non-overlapping footer at the bottom but this comes right below the content so it may not be visible with contents larger than the screen height or it may not be at the bottom with a content smaller than the screen size. I simply want **a footer which is always visible at the bottom** and which does **not overlap the content above**, regardless of the height of the content above as this is dynamic.

Comment: How can it be sticky but not overlap content? Isn't a sticky footer, by definition, sticking to the bottom of the page, regardless of page height?

Comment: 'Sticking at the bottom' does not imply overlapping with content

Comment: If the pages content can be larger (in the y axis) than the viewport of the browser, then "sticking to the bottom" definitely does imply overlap. In the situation where the content is taller than the page, what would you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give a fixed height to the content or any element. I have build a sample for you. Please have a look:

```js
let fHeight = document.querySelector('footer').offsetHeight;
document.querySelector('body').style.paddingBottom = fHeight+'px';
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: burlywood;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px;
}
footer {
  background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/cyESoU/img1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
footer h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<footer>
  <h3>This is the Footer</h3>
</footer>
```

Comment: But in your example, the footer is not always visible, only when scrolling to the end of the content

Comment: When footer will be always visible, how can you see the main content brother. Think about it.

Comment: because the footer is small and the screen is large, hence space enough for the content

Comment: I have updated my answer, Have a look on it